# E-Book Purchase Payment Gateway iOS

Tags: ios, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, payment, payment-processing

I am making an iOS app that involves the E-Book Application. In Which E-book Download locally and open within the application. 
My question here which payment gateway is suitable for payment and apple not reject that.Currently I have Implemented the in-app purchase but I doesn't wanna use that. Is there any alternative of payment gateway.

Comment: If payment is made in the app for books delivered in the app, you must use Apple IAP.  You can have payment on a website for books accessed in the app only if it isn't possible to purchase the books directly in your app - i.e. no link to the payment website from within your app.

Comment: As far as I know, if you're selling a digital good within the app, that is required by Apple to use IAPs. Stripe has [this](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios#using-stripe-and-apple-pay-vs-in-app-purchases) to say on the matter for example. But if you are selling a subscription to books for example, that might be different. You might want to clarify with Apple if you can